# High Disk Usage (PC keeps freezzing)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-explorer, svchost

OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Well I don't know when this really happens but this 2 process make the PC stop working and once I look at the HDD light it looks like HDD is working none stop.

When I try to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> the screen takes long time to show up, if even it shows up.

Once I managed to get starting the shut down process it takes forever to shut down, and most time I have to hold the power button to turn off the PC and the odd thing is that if the shut down is really slow and the shut down process is completes then PC will boot up really slow.

How do I know this because I have turned off the boot GUI so I can see the list of the drivers while loading, normal times (when PC didn't friezed/slowed down) or the times when I hold the power button to turn off then on the boot up list of drivers will load very fast as you can't see the lines, but if I let the PC shut down  normally (while everything slowed down) once I try to boot up it runs really slow each line takes like really slow then I have to run the PC in repair mode then in the scan won't show any problem but once the scan is done it will boot fast. I don't get any error code or some thing.

```
Category: Performance Alert
Date & Time,Risk,Activity,Status,Recommended Action
6/7/2013 1:15:00 AM,Info,High Disk Write usage by: Windows Explorer ,Detected,No Action Required
____________________________
Filename: explorer.exe
Full Path: c:\windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-explorer_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17567_none_afa79dc39081d0ba\explorer.exe
____________________________

Details
Reliable,  Many Users,  Mature,  Trusted

Origin
Downloaded from Unknown

Activity
Actions performed: Suspicious actions performed: None
____________________________

Developers Microsoft Corporation
Version 6.1.7601.17567
Identified 10/3/2011 at 11:01:59 PM
Last Used Not Available
Startup Item No
____________________________

Reliable
With typical use this program crashes very infrequently.

Many Users
Millions of users in the Norton Community have used this file.

Mature
This file was released more than 31 days 2 years 2 months ago.

Trusted
Norton has given this file a trusted rating.
____________________________

Source File:
explorer.exe
____________________________

Performance
____________________________

Avg. Resource Usage: Moderate
Avg. CPU Usage: Low
Avg. Memory Usage: Moderate
____________________________

Performance Alert

Process ID
1952

CPU
Normal

Memory
Normal

Handles Count
Normal

Disk Read Activity
Normal

Disk Write Activity
 371 MB (total for this process).
____________________________

File Thumbprint - SHA:
6bed1a3a956a859ef4420feb2466c040800eaf01ef53214ef9dab53aeff1cff0
File Thumbprint - MD5:
332feab1435662fc6c672e25beb37be3

**==================================================================================**

Category: Performance Alert
Date & Time,Risk,Activity,Status,Recommended Action
6/7/2013 12:24:58 AM,Info,High Disk Write usage by: Host Process for Windows Services ,Detected,No Action Required
____________________________
Filename: svchost.exe
Full Path: c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe
____________________________

Details
Reliable,  Many Users,  Mature,  Trusted

Origin
Downloaded from Unknown

Activity
Actions performed: 2
____________________________

Developers Microsoft Corporation
Version 6.1.7600.16385
Identified 3/3/2013 at 6:35:15 PM
Last Used 6/7/2013 at 3:11:29 AM
Startup Item Yes
____________________________

Reliable
With typical use this program crashes very infrequently.

Many Users
Millions of users in the Norton Community have used this file.

Mature
This file was released more than 31 days 3 years ago.

Trusted
Norton has given this file a trusted rating.
____________________________

Source File:
svchost.exe
____________________________

Performance
____________________________

Avg. Resource Usage: Low
Avg. CPU Usage: Low
Avg. Memory Usage: Low
____________________________

Performance Alert

Process ID
976

CPU
Normal

Memory
Normal

Handles Count
Normal

Disk Read Activity
Normal

Disk Write Activity
 30 MB (total for this process).
____________________________

Run Key Change

c:\windows\tasks\sa.dat
____________________________


File Thumbprint - SHA:
93b2ed4004ed5f7f3039dd7ecbd22c7e4e24b6373b4d9ef8d6e45a179b13a5e8
File Thumbprint - MD5:
c78655bc80301d76ed4fef1c1ea40a7d
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What two processes are you talking about? How do you know that they cause the problem? Is it laptop or desktop? What's your hardware? How often does it happen? What's that wall of text at the end?

Comment: Run Resource Monitor to see which process trashes the HDD so much: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/use-resource-monitor-to-monitor-storage-performance/4233

Comment: the two processes are
c:\windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-explorer_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17567_none_afa79dc39081d0ba\explorer.exe
c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe
i don't know you guys saw the Norton's report but take a look at it
my hardware VGN-FG,
Core 2 Duo T8100,
NVIDIA GeForce 8400M GT 128MB,
4GB RAM
and when or why this happens i really don't since there is no logging about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your HDD is failing. Try downloading [Acronis Drive Monitor](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/drive-monitor/) to monitor the activity and health of your HDD. When the drive has random access errors your HDD will work very hard to access system files and perform system processes.

Comment: everything shows ok other than this Current Pending Sector Count,300,197,0,Degradation

Comment: it used to happen when i used "End Process" now when i open firefox some times it happens

Comment: I'm not sure what those numbers mean. Pending sector count errors are caused by sectors that need to be remapped ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes](see this article)). As far as dealing with this, first you should update the disk firmware. This might stop the errors, but the problem could persist. If this is the case, second would be to clean wipe (use DBAN or `diskpart`) and see if the errors return. After those two, it might be time to invest in a new drive.

Comment: what is the raw value on Current Pending Sector Count.
what if Current Pending Sector Count wont go higher.
can it be the Southbridge due to high or low temp cause pc to freezzz.
I did a scan with chkdsk /B then the raw value went higher but normal value went lower from 197 to 195 note that my have 3 partitions.
1.Windows partition (53GB with 4GB free) this is the partition I scanned.
2.Page files (6GB with 200MB free).
3.All other files(404GB with 19GB free).
btw this is the model for my HDD WD5000BEVT-00A0RT0.
and the WD Data Life Guard say my hdd's health is good.